# How to implement an Expandable ListBox item use as header to show more list items using Silverlight on Windows Phone7 platform

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7, listbox

I hope someone could share an idea on how to implement a collapsable items in a listbox control with Silverlight on Windows Phone platform.

Basically, what i want to achieved is like the following behavior:

(Note: (v) represents a down arrow icon for collapsable items
       (^) represents up arrow icon to uncollapsed header items)

## Original/Unexpanded List item Headers:

```
(v) Header1  
(v) Header1
(v) Header2
(v) Header3
(v) Header4
(v) Header5
```

## Expanded Header1 with additional list items

```
(^) Header1
String1
String2
String3
(v) Header2
(v) Header3
(v) Header4
(v) Header5
```

## Expanded Header2 with additional list items

```
(v) Header1
(^) Header2
String4
String5
String6
(v) Header3
(v) Header4
(v) Header5
```

Can this be achievable with Silverlight on Windows Phone? your suggestions is highly appreciated.

Regards,
AJ